# Power BI Rank partition by two columns

Tags: powerbi, ranking

I would like to rank Partition by two Columns I have a solution using Nested Filters but is there a more efficient solution?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vDoJ.png)

I Tried the below.

```
Rank = 
VAR t = tstRank[Entity Code]
VAR t2 = tstRank[Currency Ledger]
VAR r3 =
RANKX (
    FILTER ( FILTER ( tstRank, [Currency Ledger] = t2 ), [Entity Code] = t ),
    tstRank[NetSales]
    )
RETURN
r3
```

Which has given the correct solution but is there a better way to achieve outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the obvious is to `&&` your predicates to have one table scan instead of a nested iterator:

```
Rank = 
VAR t = tstRank[Entity Code]
VAR t2 = tstRank[Currency Ledger]
RETURN
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( 
            tstRank, 
            [Currency Ledger] = t2
              && [Entity Code] = t 
        ),
        tstRank[NetSales]
    )
```